# PHP : 2258574.18 not equals to 2058555.18 + 200019 - 0

Tags: php

I'm struggling to make accounting software in PHP. And i got some bug from float precision.

***Here is the sample unworking code :***

```
$a = (float) 2258574.18;
$b = (float) 2058555.18;
$c = 200019;
$d = 0;

($b+$c-$d == $a ) ? $x = "equals" : $x = "!equals"; 
echo $x;
```

***Outputs :***

> !equals

I was using `round()` `abs()` but doesnt solved.
It work if i only convert it to int `(int)`.

*I almost suicide because of this.*

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#113703

Comment: do `echo "a:$a b:$b";` and you will see how these values are stored internally.

Comment: FYI: In console (js) doing `2058555.18 + 200019` will output `2258574.1799999997`

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: You do not want to write an accounting system using floats! Use a library which supports decimal numbers, or do all calculations in ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `round()` with precision 2

```
$e = $b+$c-$d;   
(round($e, 2) == round($a, 2) ) ? $x = "equals" : $x = "!equals"; 
echo $x;
```

Comment: Is it good to round accounting value ? I think not.